# How to use AND & OR condition in JAVA mongo db array collection

Tags: java, mongodb, conditional-operator

I have the Java Mongo Collection in the following format.

```
{
"field1": ["f1","f2"],
"field2": ["g1","g2"],        
    "Ans": a1
} 
{
    "field1": ["f4","f5"],
    "field2": ["g5","g6"],        
        "Ans": a2
} 
{
    "field1": ["f1","f6"],
    "field2": ["g2","g3"],        
        "Ans": a3
}
```

I need to do the "OR" condition in field1 and field2 separately
From the result i need to do and condition to select the row.
For example: f1,f5,g2,g3 is the input i get.
i need to do or condtion in field 1 with f1,f5 so i will get all the three rows
i need to do or condtion in field 2 with g,g3 so i will get 1st and 3rd rows
while doing and condition of both i need to get only 1st and 3rd row.
Follwing is the code im using

```
        DBObject query1 = new BasicDBObject("field1","f1");  
        DBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("field1","f5");  
        BasicDBList condtionalOperator = new BasicDBList();
        condtionalOperator.add(query1);
        condtionalOperator.add(query2);
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", condtionalOperator);
```

Similar OR query for field 2 and And query for their result
  I know its pretty long. Any one knows simple code than this?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm responding using the Mongo shell JavaScript syntax, since it's a bit less verbose than Java.  The equivalent Java should be straightforward to produce.)

```
db.collection.find({$and:[
    {field1:{$in:["f1","f5"]}},
    {field2:{$in:["g1","g3"]}}
]});
```

The `$in` operator basically does an OR operation, so the first operand of the `$and` is essentially equivalent to `{$or:[{field1:"f1"},{field1:"f5"}]}`.